# Compare two strings in FASM

Tags: string, assembly, x86, compare, fasm

I'm a newbie when it comes to FASM, and pretty new to ASM in general, but I'm trying to compare two strings stored in the "variables": `user_input` and `exit_cmd`:

At the moment, it assembles fine but when I enter anything in the prompt it crashes. Yes, my code is messy and the task I'm trying to accomplish may seem out of my reach for the level of ASM I know, but I've done it in other languages so I'm trying it out in ASM.

You can see I'm using the macro `CompareStrings` (source unknown; it's not mine) to set `EAX` to 1 if the strings match, but when I compare `EAX` to 1 using `CMP` and then `JE` to a label it refuses to work. Any help?

Here's the buggy code:

```
format PE console
;win32a.inc, win32w.inc, win64a.inc and win64w.inc
include 'win32w.inc'
entry main

; Define macros for things like printing strings ('print') and pausing (well, waiting for the user to press enter ('pause'))
macro print str {
      push str
      call [printf]
      push 0
}
macro pause {
      invoke system,'pause>nul'
}
macro getinput prompt {
      print prompt
      invoke gets,user_input
}
macro CompareStrings str1, str2
{
      lea edi, [str2]               ; edi -> address of string2
      dec edi                       ; edi = edi - 1
      .lab1:                        ; loop through all chars and compare each of them
      inc edi                       ; ds:di --> next character in string2
      lodsb                         ; al = next char from string1. loadsb increments si automatically
      cmp [edi], al                 ; compare characters
      jne .notfound                 ; jump out of the loop if they're unequal
      cmp al, 0                     ; chars are equal, but make sure we compared the entire string
      jne .lab1                     ; if not, continue the loop
      mov eax, 1                    ; else: strings are equal -> eax = 1
      ret                           ; return; result: strings are equal
      .notfound:                    ; chars are not equal
      mov eax, 0                    ; unequal -> eax = 0
      ret                           ; return; result: strings are not equal
}

section '.text' code readable executable

main:
        print header_msg
        jmp input_loop

input_loop:
        getinput cmd_prompt
        print newline
        CompareStrings user_input,cmd_exit
        cmp eax, 1
        je exit_cmd
        jne input_loop

exit_cmd:
        print header_msg
        ret

section '.data' data readable writable
        header_msg    db      "Basic Programming Language in ASM | Version 0.0.1",13,10,0
        cmd_prompt    db      "> ",0
        newline       db      "",13,10,0
        user_input    db      "",0dh,0ah,0
        chrarr        db      '%s',0dh,0ah,0
        cmd_exit      db      'exit',0

section '.idata' import data readable

library msvcrt,"msvcrt.dll"

import msvcrt,\
       puts,"puts",\
       getchar,"getchar",\
       exit,"exit",\
       printf,"printf",\
       scanf,"scanf",\
       system,"system",\
       gets,"gets"
```

Comment: `lodsb` gets `al` from `[esi]`. Where does `esi` get set?

Comment: @FrankKotler So, adding the code `mov esi, str1` before `.lab1:` should be sufficient? I tried that and the main problem remains.

Comment: I think for Masm syntax you'll need `mov esi,offset str1` or `lea esi, [str1]`. Oh wait... Fasm syntax... I dunno, that should work. Try `lea`, as you do with str2...

Comment: @FrankKotler It's not working, I don't think that's the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in this program and it is not strange it crashes.

#### Problem 1

You didn't allocated enough room for the string you input. Use `rb` directive to allocate some big enough space to handle your input:

```
user_input  rb  1024
```

Put it at the end of the data section in order to not take place in the result executable.

#### Problem 2

I don't know how the CPP library have to be used, but probably the calling convention is not STDCALL and the parameters are not exactly these. For example `gets` probably needs some kind of CPP self expandable string, not simple buffer address. Otherwise it is very easy to overflow the buffers and there is no way to check such a problem.

So, better use plain WinAPI - ReadFile and WriteFile to read and write to the console.

#### Problem 3

On the above background, it is nitpicking, but anyway:

```
  push str
  call [printf]
  push 0
```

This `push 0` looks weird here. What is is supposed to do?

#### Problem 4

Your style. Try to implement this program without using "{" and "}" characters. It will help you to understand assembly language better.

Comment: Thanks man, that `push 0` bit was left over from debugging, somewhat ironic that I forgot to remove it. As with problem 1, I'm still learning about memory allocation, so thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: @Ego - For nothing. :) But don't thanks on stackoverflow. Vote up for the useful answers and down for not useful. And what about "Problem 4"? :)

Comment: Problem 4 will take time to correct, I'm still trying to get the absolute basics down, and the correct style will follow correct syntax.

Comment: Also, I'm used to 16-bit syntax, all the registers and stuff in 32-bit are confusing as hell. I'm designed a 16-bit OS at the moment, which shows the different knowledge levels

Comment: @Ego - So wide macro use is not an "absolute basics", especially in FASM. Try to program using only the standard macros, provided by FASM includes or even not to use them at all. This approach will make the source much more easy for understanding. Anyway, good luck. :)